# Getting rid of tape lines after spraying clear coat

Tags: paint-clearcoat

Had some bumper scratches so I went ahead and bought some bondo, primer, paint and clear coat, along with 180/1000/1500/2000 grit sand paper.

After spraying clear coat and removing the tape, I noticed to thick paint lines. I attempted to wet sand one area down with 1500/2000 wet sand paper.

Here is the result. [Botched wet sanding job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXu1z.jpg)

As you can see, it's not great at all. The paint doesn't really blend well with the rest of the bumper and the tape lines are still visible. It this still salvageable?

I have another area that I haven't wet sanded yet that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qcXc.jpg)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I'm no where close to anything resembling a paint/body guy, my understanding is *you can't just spot paint something and get away with it*. You have to paint well beyond where you intend to cover, using body lines to hide most of it. Looks like you tried to paint just an area which was about maybe 3" square (in the first picture)? It just doesn't work that way. In the 2nd picture, you may be using too much material, meaning, are you sure your vehicle didn't come with a single stage paint, and yet you put multiple stages on it (clear coat?).

Comment: Do the bumper complete and possibly remove it from the vehicle... or you end up doing patches on the patches patches...

Comment: Did you polish the area after samding with something like T-Cut?

Comment: You should be able to paint and clear-coat a small area, then wet and dry sand the area flat, followed by polishing.  Here is an example I did recently- http://handyhowie.co.uk/handyhowie/Jaguar_XJS_front_wing.html

Comment: Time to hire a professional.

Comment: How to blend paint on car body: 1. Spray the area down with WD40. 2. Grab a handful of dirt, and throw it at car (dirt with high clay content is best). 3. Park the car in sun for 1 hour. The dirt will mask the differences in paint color ;)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - yea I think you may be right, I believe I am using too much material. directions on the clear coat spray can said 4-5 coats but I only did 3. still looks like too much.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I used Meguiar's Ultimate Compound in the first picture. In your post, I see you taped off a pretty large square as well. how many coats of paint did you apply? did you use clear coat? for wet/dry sanding what grits did you use? for polishing, u recommend t-cut? thanks everyone

Comment: I masked off a large area, but did not spray up to the tape, it was there to just protect against overspray.   I sprayed 2 coats of paint and 3 thick coats of clear coat.  The finest grade paper I used was 1200, then I used T-cut, but any fine cutting compound will do.

Comment: @HandyHowie ah I think that's where I made the mistake! no wonder I have such defined tape lines.. I guess at this point I would have to try to sand down the tape edges and then finish it off with compound? Unless you have another suggestion

Comment: Yes flat it down again.  If it looks like you are breaking through the clear coat, then add a couple of more coats then flat again.